# ¿Cómo poner el nombre de tabla como variable en una consulta SQL Server?

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedure

Soy nuevo en esto de `SQL Server` y quiero crear un SP que me liste todos los datos de una tabla, pero teniendo como variable la tabla a consultar.

Tenia pensado algo así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LISTAR_TODOS
(@tabla )
AS
SELECT * FROM @tabla
```

Claramente, falta el tipo de dato `@tabla`, o ¿haya otra forma de hacer eso?

Esta es mi duda, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quieres crear un Stored Procedure para seleccionar los datos de una tabla, la variable tabla sera recibida como párametro:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LISTAR_TODOS 
@tabla NVARCHAR(128) 
AS 
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tabla)     
  EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ha servido

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con la sentencia EXECUTE, el cual interpreta la cadena asignada como una serie de comandos SQL

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %s', @tabla)
INTO result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Excelente aporte, yo buscaba encontrar el máximo valor en un campo de una tabla cuyo nombre es variable. la clave esta en **QUOTENAME(@tabla)**  y usar **EXEC sp_executesql @Sqldos**

Usé este código:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON   DECLARE @Sqldos NVARCHAR(MAX);    
SET @Sqldos = 'SELECT max(idtablaimsa) as puto FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@nomtabla)   
     EXEC sp_executesql @Sqldos
```

Gracias!